# Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'float'>

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

This is somewhat of a continuation of a previous post where I should have stated that I'm still a newby to python and programming in general. I'm using xlrd and xlwt to read an excel table created using arcpy from an ArcMap featureclass after racking my brain with pyexcel_xls and xlutils (the latter two aren't installed correctly on my machine and there's nothing i can do about it at the time).

ArcMap automatically generates an object ID field which I need to get rid of before the final excel output is uploaded to .dtt file where the array is already specified and cannot be changed. Therefore, the script must open and read the excel file created using arcpy, copy all of the data into a dict excluding column 0, and then write the dict to a new workbook using xlwt. After overcoming numerous obstacles I got everything to work except for when xlwt encounters an unexpected datatype when writing the dict to the new xls file:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "N:\Python\Completed scripts\Recol1_SVRSTA00_prep2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import arcpy, xlrd, xlwt
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1030, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 257, in write
    self.__rich_text_helper(col, label, style, style_index)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 283, in __rich_text_helper
    raise Exception ("Unexpected data type %r" % type(data))
Exception: Unexpected data type <type 'float'>
```

I was wondering if I could use try and except to overcome this but I'm not sure how I would write the except statement. Otherwise, is there another way to get over this last error? Here is the script minus all the arcpy stuff (which works fine) and import module statements:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(outXL)
writeBook = r"S:\Corporate\Corporate Information\Routesmart\Recol_1\Upload\SVRSTA00.xls"

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

cell_range_value = 0
for value in sheet.col(32):
    cell_range_value += 1
print cell_range_value

dct1 = {}
for i in range(0, cell_range_value,1):
    data = [sheet.cell_value(i, col) for col in range(sheet.ncols)[1:]]
    cell_value_class = sheet.cell(i,32).value
    cell_value_id = data
    dct1[cell_value_class] = cell_value_id

workbook = xlwt.Workbook('utf-8','writeBook')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('SVRSTA00')

row = 0
col = 0

try:
    for key in dct1.keys():
        for value in dct1.values():
            worksheet.write(row, col, value)
        row += 1

except (RuntimeError,TypeError, NameError, ValueError):
    pass

workbook.save(writeBook)
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? One of its lines should tell you which part of your code is leading to exception. You might also want to comment out or otherwise get rid of your very broad `try`/`except` block at the end of your code, as suppressing errors can make debugging very difficult.

Comment: Add full traceback. I get the same message with and without try except